# Ffmpeg – Inconsistent File Segment Saves

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been running a security camera and saving the continuous video/audio in one minute segments 24 hours a day using ffmpeg.    Unfortunately I found that in the evening, ffmpeg stops saving one minute segments and starts saving two minute segments for the duration of darkness.  In the morning when the light level increases to a certain level, ffmpeg again begins saving in one minute segments.  This has been happening over several days so it is not a one time occurrence,  This creates a problem because in the two minute files, the first one minute of video is fine but at then end of that minute, the video freezes.  The result is that you watch video for one minute and then you look at the last frame of the first minute of video for the next minute.   In the end you only have a recording of what the camera is seeing every other minute,

After some investigation I found that the problem requires two conditions to trigger the change from one minute saves to two minutes saves. The amount of ambient light has to fall below a certain point and the IR illumination has to be active.    If IR illumination is off it does not matter how little light is available, the saves are still only one minute long.   If there is sufficient light, it does not matter that IR illumination is active.  The saves remain one minute long.  It takes both conditions.

Anyone have an idea of what is going on and how to prevent the two minute segments with only one minute of video?

The command line I am currently using is as follows.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -reorder_queue_size 8000 -vsync drop -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -map 0 -r 30 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/path/%d-%m-%Y__%H_%M_test.avi"`

Answer (score 0):

Same old story.  If you cannot be good, be persistent.    In case someone else comes along with a similar problem, after trying many things, this worked for me.   I am not sure all the parameters are needed, but I stopped modifying the command the instant it worked. As the old saying goes, “if isn’t broken, do not fix it”.   YMMV.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -reorder_queue_size 8000 -vsync 1  -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -map 0 -r 30 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/path/%d-%m-%Y__%H_%M_test.avi"`